# Arduino IDE not finding my library directory - Windows10

Tags: c, arduino, shared-libraries, arduino-ide

```
Arduino: 1.8.12 (Windows Store 1.8.33.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

avr-g++: error: Laptop\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LedControl-master\src": No such file or directory

avr-g++: error: C:\Users\James: No such file or directory

avr-g++: error: Laptop\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LedControl-master\src\LedControl.cpp": No such file or directory

avr-g++: warning: '-x c++' after last input file has no effect

avr-g++: fatal error: no input files

compilation terminated.

exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.
```

This is the error I'm getting. My theory is that I have a `'` in my name and it's not reading past that.

Here's my code: https://hastebin.com/olapukeyux.cs

Comment: As you already suspected a problem with special characters, have you already tried to escape them?

Comment: download the IDE from arduino.cc

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the working dir/library path in your preferences and escape it. See enclosed graphic:[image]